# Obtener información de markers seleccionado en mapa, flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter

Tengo un Widget en donde solo agrego un mapa, y dentro del mapa varios markers

Quisiera seleccionar un markers y obtener su información para pasarlo a otra ventana y mostrar sus detalles,

Por los momentos solo lo selecciono y pasa a la siguiente ventana pero trayendo todos los markers y sin saber cual es el que selecciono.

```
mapController.onInfoWindowTapped.add(_onInfoWindowTapped);


void _onInfoWindowTapped(Marker marker) {
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
    return DetailsMarkers(mapController: mapController);
  }),
);
```

}

//AGREGAR MARKERS

```
initMarker(double lat, double log, String name {
GoogleMapController mapController2 = mapController;

mapController.onInfoWindowTapped.add(_onInfoWindowTapped);
//mapController.onMarkerTapped.add(_onInfoWindowTapped);

mapController2.clearMarkers().then((val) {
  mapController2.addMarker(MarkerOptions(
    visible: true,
    draggable: true,
    flat: false,
    position: LatLng(lat,log),
    infoWindowText: InfoWindowText(name, 'Cool'),
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset("assets/images/icono_gas.png"),
  )
  );
});}
```

Comment: puedes agregar la parte donde agregas el marker y que información quieres obtener

Comment: Este seria el codigo, pero no se si es la mejor forma, estoy viendo unos ejelpos en donde tienen una clase Place.

Yo quisiera obtener en la otra ventana el nombre, descripcion y posicion.

Comment: agrega el código en la pregunta, para que pueda leerse bien, edita la pregunta

Comment: Quisiera tener una lista con todos los markers y dentro de ella tener todos los detalles de la misma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, puedes crear una variable global , donde puedas almacenar la info de tus markers.

```
        Map<String,String> markerMap = Map();
```

Luego al momento de agregar los markers, agregas el id como key en el Map.

```
        initMarker(double lat, double log, String name {
        GoogleMapController mapController2 = mapController;

        mapController.onInfoWindowTapped.add(_onInfoWindowTapped);
        //mapController.onMarkerTapped.add(_onInfoWindowTapped);

        mapController2.clearMarkers().then((val) async {

           final marker = await  mapController2.addMarker(MarkerOptions(
            visible: true,
            draggable: true,
            flat: false,
            position: LatLng(lat,log),
            infoWindowText: InfoWindowText(name, 'Cool'),
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset("assets/images/icono_gas.png"),
          )
          );

          //agrega el id del marker en tu Map


          markerMap[marker.id] = name;


        });}
```

Finalmente, cuando das tap al marker, obtienes la información:

```
        void _onInfoWindowTapped(Marker marker) {

            final data = markerMap[marker.id];
            print("Data: $data");

            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return DetailsMarkers(mapController: mapController);
              }),
            );



        }
```

Comment: Al agregar 
markerMap[marker.id] = name;
Me dice que marker.id no esta definido ??

Comment: actualicé mi respuesta,    Map<String,String> markerMap = Map();

Comment: sigue igual, y lo agregue asi tambien= Map<String, String> markerMap = Map<String,String>(); y tampoco

Comment: hiciste como lo puse en el código?  final marker = await  mapController2.addMarker(   ... 
ahí es donde obtienes la referencia a marker,  y no te olvides del  async {

Comment: el primer markerMap[marker.id] = name;  que esta arriba de initMarker(double lat, double log, String name) { 

que seria?

Comment: si ese lo agregue

Comment: error mío :) , borraré eso

Comment: si eso no lo coloque pero igual el marker.id sigue sin identificarlo.

Comment: puedes entrar al código de : addMarker  y ver que tiene? puede ser que estés usando una versión desactualizada de la lib

Comment: Ya logre que funcionara lo que me pasaste, pero me esta abriendo la otra ventana por cada markers que tengo. es decir void _onInfoWindowTapped(Marker marker) { me llos trae todos. necesito solo el que seleccione.

Comment: esta linea : mapController.onInfoWindowTapped.add(_onInfoWindowTapped); , solo debe llamarse una vez, no cada vez que agregas un marker

Comment: Excelente..!! muchas gracias por la ayuda. 

una pregunta y si le quiero pasar alguna otra informacion como alguna descripcion o algo mas?

Comment: tendrías que asignarle un Objeto con datos, en lugar de solo el nombre, aquí:  markerMap[marker.id] = name;  , tendria que ser algo como  :  markerMap[marker.id] = tuObjeto, map, o lo que sea;  y aquí sería el tipo de dato que le vas a asignar,   Map<String,tu_tipo_de_Dato_aquí> markerMap = Map();